# Which large countries use 12-hour time format (AM/PM)?

Tags: factoids, local-customs, countries

Odd question:

Which (large) countries uses/prefers 12-hour time format (AM/PM)?

I understand that US, UK, Canada, Australia mostly use 12-hour (though also 24-hour in some cases).

But there must be a great deal more, even though 24-hour format is dominant. Can't find any list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about a problem or question relating to travelling

Comment: @Gagravarr I kinda see it. But if I remove "It's for a website", then it could easily be about travelling. Can you tell me where I could ask such a question then?

Comment: Whether it's for a web site or not, it's not about travel.

Comment: Knowing what time standard is used in different countries seems very relevant to travel.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quite a good resource is imho the standard clock setting in Microsoft Windows installations:
[image]
image from talkstandards.com

As you can see, it's particularly North America, India, the Philippines, Colombia, Egypt, Saudi Arabia, and Australia

This is more or less confirmed by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country) that states that

> in most English-speaking regions, particularly the United States, the
>   Philippines and the United Kingdom and its former colonies, the
>   12-hour clock is the predominant form of stating the time.

Comment: Done. Country codes for countries mostly using 12-hour format: US, UK, PH, CA, AU, NZ, IN, EG, SA, CO, PK, MY

Comment: This is incorrect. The default clock settings in Vietnamese locale in Windows is still 12-hour format. People also commonly use 12-hour format although official documents must be in 24-hour format

Comment: SG (Singapore) is missing in the above list @mowgli

Comment: Furthermore ZA (South Africa) is not highlighted in the image, but my research shows they normally use the 12 hour clock as well.

Comment: @mowgli: 'UK' isn't an ISO country code. You probably mean 'GB'.

Comment: Also, the Wikipedia map currently shows much of the Middle East and northern Africa as using 12-hour time, but the code list only includes Saudi Arabia and Egypt.